# How to append to a template after a join

Tags: python

I am running short of ideas on how can I do this?I really need some help...I am trying to generate HTML code based on an input XML file and running into attribute error,problem is I am using "TR_TEMPLATE = '\n'.join(TR_TEMPLATE)" which becomes a string ,later on again my code I try to append "TR_TEMPLATE.append('    {{}}'.format(col))" which is causing an error..I cant remove the join in the first place ,how do I proceed?

My code:-

```
    http://pastie.org/5390303
```

INput is below

```
http://pastie.org/5390316
```

Expected output:-

```
http://pastie.org/5390312
```

Attribute error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Dropbox\scripts\test.py", line 54, in <module>
crInfo = CRlistToTable(CRlist)
File "C:\Dropbox\scripts\test.py", line 31, in CRlistToTable
TR_TEMPLATE.append('    <td>{{}}</td>'.format(col))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Why can't you remove the join in the first place? If you can keep things in a list as long as possible, and then convert to a string at the end, it will be much simpler (as well as probably more efficient, but that's not as important). Also, why use the same variable name for the joined-up string as for the original list? It will be easier to read if you use different variables?

Comment: @abarnert - If I do that I am not getting the correct output..please see my current output http://pastie.org/5390348 and the expected output http://pastie.org/5390312

Comment: Well, you're not getting the correct output—or any output—this way. What makes you think that's going to fix anything? PS, why are there no quotes around the href in line 23? Can you show the code that actually generated the incorrect output, instead of a different version that doesn't even get that far?

Comment: @abarnert - Here is the exact code http://pastie.org/5390372

Comment: When I run the code at that URL against the input given above, I get a `KeyError: 'CR  FA  CL  Title` on line 37 `CRstrings.append(TR_TEMPLATE.format(CR=items[0], *items[1:]))`. Are you sure that's the same code that's running but generating an error? Meanwhile, again, what made you think that adding a `join` at line 26 would fix whatever problem you were having?

Comment: @abarnert - you are getting that errror because your input is not right,the input I provided should be pasted into and excel to be sure that tehy are tab seperated... ya,removing the join wont fix the problem..there is some logical problem with my code

Comment: Removing the `join` definitely does fix the problem you're asking about in your question—the `AttributeError` you didn't expect or understand and wanted to get rid of. I still have no idea why you added that `join` in the first place, and even less idea why you think "I cant remove the join", and I've run out of ways to ask those questions. Since I can't fathom what you're trying to do, and you haven't even given us input in a format we can use, all I can say is, I hope someone else can help you. Sorry.

Comment: ok fine..I will start a different thread..subject is misleading

Comment: is there a way to attach a file?

Comment: No, just upload the file to, e.g., pastebin, then put a link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least four possibilities here, in order from simplest-and-probably-best to most-nightmarish.

First, you can just scrap line 26. Although you say "I cant remove the join in the first place", there doesn't seem to be any good reason for that.

You're eventually guaranteed to join it up in line 33, and you don't ever use the value before that, except to append more strings. So, why is line 26 there at all?

Second, you can change line 26 from this:

```
TR_TEMPLATE = '\n'.join(TR_TEMPLATE)
```

to this:

```
TR_TEMPLATE = ['\n'.join(TR_TEMPLATE)]
```

In other words, instead of flattening it from a list of strings to a single string, flatten it from a list of strings to a list of one string—which you can then go on appending more strings to and flattening again.

Third, you can make `TR_TEMPLATE` a string instead of a list in the first place. Change line 13 to leave the brackets out. Then, everywhere you call `TR_TEMPLATE.append(foo)`, instead just do `TR_TEMPLATE += foo + '\n'`. Then you can scrap lines 26, and change line 33 to just remove the extra trailing '\n' instead of joining.

Finally, you can keep track of whether you've joined up `TR_TEMPLATE` yet, and `append` if you haven't, concatenate if you have. (Or, instead of keeping track, you could use type switching, but that makes it even uglier.)

Comment: how to delete this post?